# Forcing locale in Laravel Dusk

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

How can we force the locale used by Dusk within our tests?

The browser is launched with FR locale set and thus my application is outputting French.

I would need to make all tests consistently, regardless of the locale set by the developer on his system when running tests.

In the middleware stack, I have a `LocaleMiddleware` responsible for picking a locale based on the request headers (sent automatically by the browser).

If possible, I would like to avoid having test-specific code within the application code (as suggested below, to force a locale when environment is 'testing')

Answer (score 2):

Use `setLocale()` method:

```
app()->setLocale('en');
```

Or:

```
App::setLocale('en');
```

> You may also change the active language at runtime using the `setLocale` method

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization#introduction

**Update**

You can also set locale in the middleware for testing environment:

```
if (env('APP_ENV') === 'testing') {
    app()->setLocale('en');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Where do you use that? Within the test? My app has a global middleware which sets the locale to whichever value sent by the browser in the headers, Hence setting the locale from the test itself does not work as it gets overwritten later on.

Comment: Have you tried to use `WithoutMiddleware` trait? Also, inside middleware you could check the environment and choose to not override the locale. Or you could even set the `en` locale there for the testing environment.

Comment: Not really keen on having code dedicated to tests within production code (within Middleware). That was an option I was keeping as last resort. Wanted to get Dusk configured. Downvoted because it did not answer the question (though I must say the question was laking precision). Will be happy to upvote now because of the middleware suggestion.

Comment: Additionally, I have some tests which make sure the locale middleware is working as expected. Those tests will be broken if I use your approach to test the application environment.

Comment: `if (env('APP_ENV') === 'testing')` <=> `if (app()->environment('testing'))` too